# is this grammar context free

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, context-sensitive-grammar

is the following grammar context free? My impression was that a grammar was context free when the parser did not need to interpret what was parsed already. With the following grammar, that is not necessary, however, my colleague is sure that it is context sensitive non the less.

The issue is that you cannot determine which alternative of X needs to be matched without knowing if X is inside Y or Z

```
X: ( "a" | "a" "b" )
Y: X "b" "c"
Z: X "d"
```

Comment: "you cannot determine which alternative of X needs to be matched without knowing if X is inside Y or Z" - that implies there are rules that you have not encoded in your grammar...

Comment: `which alternative of X` - ? X is X. It appears that this grammar has two entry-points, though, `Y` and `Z`, which is not how grammars are usually presented.

Comment: You need to restate this question to match your issue.  As presented X can be matched with two tokens of look ahead -- if "a" is followed by "b" and "c" it's Y, else it's X.  Not LALR1, but definitely context free.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it would be trivial to rewrite this example to have 1 entry point that either uses Y or Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "context sensitive" occasionally arises when discussing grammars that work with LL parsers but not with Strong LL (SLL) parsers. In these cases, decisions that require an LL parser may be called "context sensitive" because they require information about the top-down parsing context to make accurate decisions. However, both SLL and LL grammars would be considered context-free grammars.

Comment: That's a *very* idiosyncratic definition of "context-sensitive", which is almost always used to refer to Type-1 grammars in the Chomsky hierarchy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)

Comment: @rici you're right, and this really is far from ideal. However, I don't know another term for this situation, and the specific wording "...without knowing if X is inside Y or Z" leads me to believe the OP's colleague is considering the situation from this point of view.